# Azure Ruby SDK create public blob

Tags: ruby, azure, blob, containers

I'm having an issue where I'm creating a container programmatically using the Ruby SDK, and it is being set to Private immediately.

I'm using the Azure Ruby SDK found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby

```
def create_container(container_name)
  container = Azure.blobs.create_container(container_name)
end
```

How do I set the access level to Public Blob? Right now I have to go to the portal and set it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the code from [`here`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ruby-how-to-use-blob-storage/) :)

```
container = azure_blob_service.create_container("test-container", :public_access_level => "container")
```